# SHA1 Validation of geodatabase

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have downloaded geodatabase from arcgis and i tried to validate by its hash with server hash after opening it programatically. The `SHA1` hash value get changed if the geodatabase was opened to display in a mapview. But it should be same all the time.

Hash value get modified by itself after it was opened. I found that two support files (extensions with ...-wal & ...-shm)has been created automatically. Need advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here my try

```
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:293]
                                                  forKey: NSFilePosixPermissions];

NSFileManager* mngr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

BOOL isChanged = [mngr setAttributes:attrs ofItemAtPath:pgnPath error:&err];
NSLog(@"isChanged: %d", isChanged);
```

you can check the file's privilege in file's info

[image]